# Why the UserControle not visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications

I try to make border as a Notification i working with WPF. So i created UserControle represent a notification card, here is the Xaml code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Try2.OurNotification"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup- 
   compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:Try2="clr-namespace:Try2"
        Width="350">
    <Border Name="BrdNotifay" Style="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Try2:ThemeKey}, ResourceId=ToastCard}}">
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Style="{StaticResource 
  {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Try2:ThemeKey}, 
   ResourceId=ToastIcon}}">
                <Canvas Style="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Try2:ThemeKey}, ResourceId=ToastIconCanvas}}">
                    <Path x:Name="Ico"  Width="38" Height="38" 
Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="19" Stretch="Fill" Fill="White" Data="F1 M 
 31.6667,19L 44.3333,19L 57,31.6667L 57,44.3333L 44.3333,57L 31.6667,57L 
 19,44.3333L 19,31.6667L 31.6667,19 Z M 26.4762,45.0454L 30.9546,49.5238L 
 38,42.4783L 45.0454,49.5238L 49.5237,45.0454L 42.4783,38L 49.5238,30.9546L 
 45.0454,26.4763L 38,33.5217L 30.9546,26.4762L 26.4762,30.9546L 33.5217,38L 
  26.4762,45.0454 Z "/>
                </Canvas>
        </TextBlock>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
 AncestorType=Try2:OurNotification, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                       Style="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
  TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Try2:ThemeKey}, ResourceId=ToastTitle}}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message, RelativeSource= 
 {RelativeSource AncestorType=Try2:OurNotification, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                       Style="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
 TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Try2:ThemeKey}, ResourceId=ToastMessage}}" />
        </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
 </UserControl>
```

and here is the code behind of this "UserControl"

```
 public OurNotification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public OurNotification(FrameworkElement owner, string title, string message,
         ToasterAnimation animation, double margin)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = title;
        Message = message;

        Animation = animation;
        Margins = margin;

        var story = NotifiayDefinations.GetAnimation(Animation,BrdNotifay);
        story.Completed += (sender, args) => { Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; };
        story.Begin(BrdNotifay);
    }

    #region Message

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Message", typeof(string), typeof(OurNotification), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    #endregion

    #region Title

    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Title", typeof(string), typeof(OurNotification), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    #endregion

    #region Animation

    public ToasterAnimation Animation
    {
        get { return (ToasterAnimation)GetValue(AnimationProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimationProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimationProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Animation", typeof(ToasterAnimation), typeof(OurNotification), new UIPropertyMetadata(ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromTop));

    #endregion

    #region Margins

    public double Margins
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MarginsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MarginsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarginsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Margins", typeof(double), typeof(OurNotification), new UIPropertyMetadata(0D));

    #endregion
```

i have theme dictionary and class "themekey" for change the themes however,
i created class "NotifiayDefinations.cs" that's contains the all definitions needed and the animation method. here is the code.

```
public static class Helper
 {
    public static SolidColorBrush ToSolidColorBrush(this string hex)
    {
        var convertFromString = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(hex);
        var color = (Color?)convertFromString ?? Colors.Black;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }
}

public static class NotificationIcoPath
{
    public static readonly Geometry Success = Geometry.Parse("F1 M23.7501 37.25 L34.8334 48.3333 L52.2499 26.1668 L56.9999 30.9168 L34.8334 57.8333 L19.0001 42 L23.7501 37.25 Z ");
    public static readonly Geometry Info = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 38,19C 48.4934,19 57,27.5066 57,38C 57,48.4934 48.4934,57 38,57C 27.5066,57 19,48.4934 19,38C 19,27.5066 27.5066,19 38,19 Z M 33.25,33.25L 33.25,36.4167L 36.4166,36.4167L 36.4166,47.5L 33.25,47.5L 33.25,50.6667L 44.3333,50.6667L 44.3333,47.5L 41.1666,47.5L 41.1666,36.4167L 41.1666,33.25L 33.25,33.25 Z M 38.7917,25.3333C 37.48,25.3333 36.4167,26.3967 36.4167,27.7083C 36.4167,29.02 37.48,30.0833 38.7917,30.0833C 40.1033,30.0833 41.1667,29.02 41.1667,27.7083C 41.1667,26.3967 40.1033,25.3333 38.7917,25.3333 Z ");
    public static readonly Geometry Error = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 31.6667,19L 44.3333,19L 57,31.6667L 57,44.3333L 44.3333,57L 31.6667,57L 19,44.3333L 19,31.6667L 31.6667,19 Z M 26.4762,45.0454L 30.9546,49.5238L 38,42.4783L 45.0454,49.5238L 49.5237,45.0454L 42.4783,38L 49.5238,30.9546L 45.0454,26.4763L 38,33.5217L 30.9546,26.4762L 26.4762,30.9546L 33.5217,38L 26.4762,45.0454 Z ");
    public static readonly Geometry Warning = Geometry.Parse("F1 M 38,19C 48.4934,19 57,27.5066 57,38C 57,48.4934 48.4934,57 38,57C 27.5066,57 19,48.4934 19,38C 19,27.5066 27.5066,19 38,19 Z M 34.0417,25.7292L 36.0208,41.9584L 39.9792,41.9583L 41.9583,25.7292L 34.0417,25.7292 Z M 38,44.3333C 36.2511,44.3333 34.8333,45.7511 34.8333,47.5C 34.8333,49.2489 36.2511,50.6667 38,50.6667C 39.7489,50.6667 41.1667,49.2489 41.1667,47.5C 41.1667,45.7511 39.7489,44.3333 38,44.3333 Z ");
}
public static class NotificationColor
{
    public static readonly SolidColorBrush Success = "#4BA253".ToSolidColorBrush();
    public static readonly SolidColorBrush Info = "#5EAEC5".ToSolidColorBrush();
    public static readonly SolidColorBrush Error = "#C43829".ToSolidColorBrush();
    public static readonly SolidColorBrush Warning = "#FF9400".ToSolidColorBrush();
}

public enum ToastType
{
    Error,
    Info,
    Success,
    Warning
}

public enum ToasterAnimation
{
    FadeIn,
    SlideInFromRight,
    SlideInFromLeft,
    SlideInFromTop,
    SlideInFromBottom,
    GrowFromRight,
    GrowFromLeft,
    GrowFromTop,
    GrowFromBottom,
}
internal class NotifiayDefinations
{
    public static StoryBoard GetAnimation(ToasterAnimation animation, UIElement toaster)
    {
        var story = new StoryBoard();

        switch (animation)
        {
            case ToasterAnimation.FadeIn:
                DoubleAnimation fadein = new DoubleAnimation(0, 1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                {
                    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
                };
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadein, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Opacity)"));
                story.Children.Add(fadein);
                DoubleAnimation fadeout = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                {
                    BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)
                };
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeout, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.Opacity)"));
                story.Children.Add(fadeout);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromRight:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1, 0);
                toaster.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(300.0, 0);
                var slideinFromRightAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)),
                    KeyFrames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection
                    {
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.1), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut
                        }),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.8)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.9), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
                        })
                    }
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideinFromRightAnimation,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                story.Children.Add(slideinFromRightAnimation);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromLeft:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
                toaster.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-300.0, 0);
                var slideinFromLeftAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)),
                    KeyFrames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection
                    {
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(-300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.1), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut
                        }),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.8)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(-300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.9), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
                        })
                    }
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideinFromLeftAnimation,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));
                story.Children.Add(slideinFromLeftAnimation);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromTop:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
                toaster.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, 300);
                var slideinFromTopAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)),
                    KeyFrames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection
                    {
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(-300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.1), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut
                        }),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.8)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(-300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.9), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
                        })
                    }
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideinFromTopAnimation,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)"));
                story.Children.Add(slideinFromTopAnimation);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromBottom:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
                toaster.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(0, -300);
                var slideinFromBottomAnimation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                {
                    Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)),
                    KeyFrames = new DoubleKeyFrameCollection
                    {
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.1), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut
                        }),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(0.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.8)),
                        new EasingDoubleKeyFrame(300.0, KeyTime.FromPercent(0.9), new ExponentialEase
                        {
                            EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseOut
                        })
                    }
                };

                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slideinFromBottomAnimation,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.Y)"));
                story.Children.Add(slideinFromBottomAnimation);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.GrowFromRight:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1, 0);
                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames growfromright = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                growfromright.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
                growfromright.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
                growfromright.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
                growfromright.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growfromright,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
                story.Children.Add(growfromright);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.GrowFromLeft:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames growfromleft = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                growfromleft.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
                growfromleft.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
                growfromleft.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
                growfromleft.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growfromleft,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));
                story.Children.Add(growfromleft);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.GrowFromTop:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1, 0);
                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames growfromtop = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                growfromtop.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
                growfromtop.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
                growfromtop.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
                growfromtop.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growfromtop,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));
                story.Children.Add(growfromtop);
                break;
            case ToasterAnimation.GrowFromBottom:
                toaster.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0, 1);
                DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames growfrombottom = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
                growfrombottom.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)));
                growfrombottom.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5)));
                growfrombottom.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)));
                growfrombottom.KeyFrames.Add(new SplineDoubleKeyFrame(0, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.5)));
                Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(growfrombottom,
                    new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));
                story.Children.Add(growfrombottom);
                break;
        }

        return story;
    }


}
```

}

than i created call named "CallNotifiactions.cs" to change color and icon for notification card and i call it here is the code of "CallNotifiactions.cs"

```
 public static class CallNotifiactions
{
    private static OurNotification GetToasterWindow(FrameworkElement owner, ToastType type, string title, string message,
         ToasterAnimation animation, double margin)
    {
        var toaster = new OurNotification(owner, title, message, animation, margin);
        switch (type)
        {
            case ToastType.Error:
                toaster.Ico.Data = NotificationIcoPath.Error;
                toaster.BrdNotifay.Background = NotificationColor.Error;
                break;
            case ToastType.Info:
                toaster.Ico.Data = NotificationIcoPath.Info;
                toaster.BrdNotifay.Background = NotificationColor.Info;
                break;
            case ToastType.Warning:
                toaster.Ico.Data = NotificationIcoPath.Warning;
                toaster.BrdNotifay.Background = NotificationColor.Warning;
                break;
            case ToastType.Success:
                toaster.Ico.Data = NotificationIcoPath.Success;
                toaster.BrdNotifay.Background = NotificationColor.Success;
                break;
        }
        return toaster;
    }

    public static void ShowError(
     Window owner,
     string title = "Error",
     string message = "Something terrible may have just happened and you are being notified of it.",

     ToasterAnimation animation = ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromRight,
     double margin = 10.0)
    {
        var toaster = GetToasterWindow(owner, ToastType.Error, title, message, animation, margin);
        toaster.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
    }


}
```

}

finaly i go to "mainwindow" and i call method that responsible to what kind of notification appear here is

```
            CallNotifiactions.ShowError(this, "Error", "Boof", ToasterAnimation.SlideInFromTop, 10);
```

the code worked fine but the "UserControle" doesn't visible and i don't reach why the notification doesn't visible? 
Where is the mistake؟

I hope to help me please,

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain what you were trying to do and at what event your "UserControle" is not visible. Also, please add only the code that is required for this issue.

Comment: I trying to showing up the "UserControle" as a notification this code related together, the code working but the "UserControle" not showing up in main window